# Huge proglem to load Plotly plots in Jupyter Notebook Python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, jupyter, seaborn

I have a huge problem with Jupyter Notebook. 
When he builds graphs using the plot packet, to display the next graph I have to reload the dataset, otherwise an error pops up: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices`, not str. When I reopen the project, all the graphs created using Plotly are not visible, just a white background and I have to reload them if I want to see them, and everything after reloading the dataset, that is:

1) I open the project in Jupyte Notebook, all graphs created by Plotly are not visible (others from Seaborn for example are visible.

2) I load the Plotly charts, but I can load them one by one, because first I have to load the dataset, then the chart, and so an error occurs to all Plotly charts differently: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices`

what can I do about it how to fix it? it seriously hinders the work

this is my libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.tools as tls
```

This is an example of this error, but if I load the dataset again and again load this plot everything will be ok: 
[image]

and the example of the code of plot:

```
#Distribution of credit risk in dataset (target variable)

#Size of the plot
figsize=(10,5)

#Sums of good and bad credits in the dataset
goodCount = data[data["Risk"]== 'good']["Risk"].value_counts().values
badCount = data[data["Risk"]== 'bad']["Risk"].value_counts().values

#Bar fo good credit
trace0 = go.Bar(x = data[data["Risk"]== 'good']["Risk"].value_counts().index.values,
               y = data[data["Risk"]== 'good']["Risk"].value_counts().values,
               name='Good credit',
               text= goodCount, 
               textposition="auto", 
               marker = dict(color = "green", line=dict(color="black", width=1),),opacity=1)

#Bar of bad credit
trace1 = go.Bar(x = data[data["Risk"]== 'bad']["Risk"].value_counts().index.values,
               y = data[data["Risk"]== 'bad']["Risk"].value_counts().values,
               name='Bad credit', 
               text= badCount, 
               textposition="auto", 
               marker = dict(color = "red", line=dict(color="black", width=1),),opacity=1)

#Creation of bar plot 
data = [trace0, trace1]
layout = go.Layout()
layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(title='Count'),
                   xaxis=dict(title='Risk variable'),
                   title='Distribution of target variable in the dataset')


fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Plotly runs active JavaScript but that is blocked upon reopening the notebook for security reasons. You can view the notebook saved with nbviewer and the plotly plots will show up.

Comment: In the middle of [this notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/fomightez/7c7e4ba777f5084b334c4407453e8dfb) are two plotly plots visible in nbviewer. You’ll see they are not visible at source gist site or upon reopening active notebook.

Comment: Alternatively you save the plot as an image and reference that in another cell, see [here](https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/).